# Why did this regex pass?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering why this regex solution matches, when it clearly should not. The link to the question website is [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/problem/matching_decimal_numbers).

`^(-?)(\d+)(\.|,)?(\w+)\.?(\d+)$`

```
Task   Text
---------------------
Match  3.14529 
Match  -255.34 
Match  128 
Match  1.9e10  
Match  123,340.00  
Skip   720p
```

The regex above should be accepted.

Comment: It seems that if it clearly should not, the question is answered: a bug in the site.  Is there a specific question about which ones clearly should not?

Comment: Why do you say _"it clearly should not"_? To me, it clearly _should_ match. What do you think is wrong with that regex that makes you think it shouldn't match?  The Match and Skip that are shown are all correct.

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Which line do you think is wrongly judged? (although the regexp matches way more than floats, there is no counterexample that would defeat it, like `123A123`).

Comment: What browser are you using? When I put in that regex in that website, it *is* accepted - it matches the ones it should match and skips the one it shouldn't match.

Comment: The regex they give in _"or read the Solution."_ is a much better regex than the one in your question. Your regex correctly matches and doesn't match their examples, but yours will match many things it shouldn't if you were to expand the base of examples. But, at face value, there is nothing wrong with the fact that your regex matches their examples.

Comment: This is a stupid lesson, telling no solution, you can enter anything, a good solution would look something like this: `^-?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?(e-?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)?$`

Comment: @maraca: "telling no solution"... except when you click on "read the Solution".

Comment: @Amadan yes now I saw it, the site isn't too bad the visualization is good, but the learning effect is small, it almost sounds like you are one of the authors ;-) I just think it could be greatly improved by checking against a bunch of hidden strings when clicking continue and then display a few of the failing strings if not working. The check as is is usless, visualization is good.

Comment: I have absolutely no affiliation to the site. The check checks exactly what it says it does, no more, no less. However, what purpose would hidden strings do? A website can teach you regexp, but it can't teach you to think (even if it can pose trick questions). I always *hated* "problem solving" websites that would give me "Failed on a test case", without telling me what the test case is. That is quality assurance training, not programming training.

Comment: @Amadan please... I said display a few of the failing strings... otherwise it would be stupid. The few they have chosen to visualize is a pretty good representation and it doesn't make sense to extend that, but to say hey this fails for the following 3 strings and you can go back to improve if you like.

Comment: And I mean what kind of explanation is this? The given solution fails for 1e10 because it only accepts e after a dot on the other hand 1,2,3 is a valid number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's evaluate this regex.

```
                                             ^(-?)(\d+)(\.|,)?(\w+)\.?(\d+)$
                                             |---||---||-----||---||-||----|
           may or may not start with a hyphen__|    |     |     |   |    |
         then must contain one or more digits_______|     |     |   |    |
then may or may not contain a period or comma_____________|     |   |    |
then must contain one or more word characters___________________|   |    |
         then may or may not contain a period_______________________|    |
          then must end in one or more digits____________________________|
```

The only test string in your group that does not match that is 720p.  Interesting thing to note, 1 would not match, 0.0 would not match or many other valid numbers.  So it's not a great regular expression for numbers, but it does work with those test cases.